# Using a page.on('response') eventEmitter listener in Playwright automatic fixture

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, playwright

I am attempting to create a page.on('response') event listener fixture that will be used across all my tests.

Currently, whenever there are certain events in my code base that will cause a div with a specific ID to appear in the UI.
I was able to get this to work by creating a separate method and including that in a beforeEach hook, however I was wondering if this would be possible to implement as an automatic fixture.

// helper.js

```
exports.test = base.test.extend({
  responseMacroErrorCheck: [async ({ page }) => {
    page.on('response', data => {
      if (data) {
        data.body().then(b => {
          let ioCheck = b.indexOf('example')
          if (b && ioCheck !== -1) {
            process.stdout.write(`Macro error detected on page (example)`)
            process.stdout.write(`${b.toString().substring(ioCheck - 500, ioCheck + 500)}`)
            throw new Error(`Macro error detected on page (example)\n${b})}`)
          }
        })
      }
    })
    await use('responseMacroErrorCheck')
  }, { scope: 'test', auto: true }],
})
```

// error.spec.js

```
const scanUrlList = [
  'myUrl'
]

test.describe('Scan URL list for macro errors', () => {
  scanUrlList.forEach(ele => {
    test(ele, async ({ page }) => {
      await page.goto(`myUrl`)
    })
  })
})
```

The above method seems to make it so that `responseMacroErrorCheck` is not recognized by the code, however if I add the following code it runs just fine and as intended
// helper.js

```
export const responseMacroErrorCheck = async (page) => {
  page.on('response', data => {
    if (data) {
      data.body().then(b => {
        let ioCheck = b.indexOf('example')
        if (b && ioCheck !== -1) {
          process.stdout.write(`Macro error detected on page (example)`)
          process.stdout.write(`${b.toString().substring(ioCheck - 500, ioCheck + 500)}`)
          throw new Error(`Macro error detected on page (example)\n${b})}`)
        }
      })
    }
  })
}
```

// error.spec.js

```
  test.beforeEach(async ({ page }) => {
    await h.responseMacroErrorCheck(page)
  })
```

Is there something I am missing in my automatic fixture? Or is it just that page emitted events are not recognizable in automatic fixtures?

Comment: Just to be sure, you are doing `import {test} from helper.js` and not `import {test} from @playwright/test` ?

Comment: @candre welp. That is exactly what I needed. I was importing it from /test - Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Had to: `import {test} from helper.js` and not `import {test} from @playwright/test`